# Multivariate zero_one_inflated_beta regression

Tags: r, bayesian, zero-inflation, multivariate-regression, beta-regression

I want to run a `zero_one_inflated_beta` regression with `brms` on the following multivariate formula:

```
mvbind(pleasure, intensity) ~  p_cat * i_cat + age + gender +  (1|item) + (1|subject)
```

*pleasure* and *intensity* are continuous response scores in $[0, 1]$.

*`p_cat`* and *`i_cat`* are categorical variables with 3 levels each: (negative, neutral, positive), and (low, medium, high), correspondingly.

This model only provides the *mu* coefficients of the beta regression for my covariates. What about *phi* (precision), *zoi* (zero-or-one inflation probability) and *coi* (conditional-one probability) coefficients?

Following the ZOIB model in [Matti Vuorre's tutorial](https://vuorre.netlify.com/post/2019/02/18/analyze-analog-scale-ratings-with-zero-one-inflated-beta-models/), I tried the following formula:

```
bf(
mvbind(pleasure, intensity) ~  p_cat * i_cat + age + gender +  (1|item) + (1|subject), 
phi ~ p_cat * i_cat + age + gender +  (1|item) + (1|subject),
zoi ~ p_cat * i_cat + age + gender +  (1|item) + (1|subject),
coi ~ p_cat * i_cat + age + gender +  (1|item) + (1|subject),
family = zero_one_inflated_beta()
)
```

1. In terms of interpretation, is it like the first formula only explains effects on the $(0, 1)$ part of my responses, and I need some or all of the *phi*, *zoi*, and *coi* coefficients (from the second formula) to get a more informed understanding of the effects? Or the *mu* coefficients are already influenced by zero and one inflation, so their analysis should be informative enough?
2. With the first formula I get overall values for_phi_, *zoi*, and *coi* in the *Family Specific Parameters*. How should I interpret them? I have the impression that these, unlike *mu* coefficients, are in the original scale and not logits, although I called `family = zero_one_inflated_beta(link = "logit", link_phi = "log", link_zoi = "logit", link_coi = "logit")`.

```
 Family: MV(zero_one_inflated_beta, zero_one_inflated_beta) 
  Links: mu = logit; phi = identity; zoi = identity; coi = identity
         mu = logit; phi = identity; zoi = identity; coi = identity 

Family Specific Parameters: 
            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
phi_pleasure    8.36      0.63     7.18     9.63 1.00     8370     6388
phi_intensity   8.36      0.61     7.22     9.60 1.00     7822     6134
zoi_pleasure    0.01      0.01     0.00     0.03 1.00     9303     4817
zoi_intensity   0.01      0.01     0.00     0.02 1.00     8625     4458
coi_pleasure    0.67      0.18     0.29     0.95 1.00     9784     5652
coi_intensity   0.40      0.20     0.07     0.80 1.00    11271     5317
```

3. Overall, do you think I should put more effort to get the second model to converge and understand the interpretations of *phi*, *zoi*, and *coi* coefficients (not sure if that is what people call a distributional model), or just interpreting the *mu* coefficients of the first model should be enough?